# Typo3 BE list_view creation?

Tags: listview, typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

I need to make a new list out of an existing one without loosing the connection.

lets say I have an entry set of "cats", I somehow need to produce a list with only "cats" that have the flag "red". I need to list all "cats" within this page tree but they are not in the same folder. I would love a way, a simple BE user could do that but I suspect there will be a doing for me. how can I create "red cat" only lists in Typo3 BE?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it extBase extension created by extension builder?

Answer (score 0):

The single table view lets you sort by property. This is probably not good enough for you as it is not a filtered list and it only display records from a single pid (the one you have selected in the page tree).

Your best option would be to create an extension with a backend module. Add a list action to the controller and query against the repository where your cats are stored. Remember to set the default query settings correctly to not respect the pid or the record (respectStoragePid).

Also, the default location of your backend Templates might be buggy as generated by the extension builder (if you decide to use that).